# Attaching objects relatvive to static background in Android

Tags: android, layout, background

I'm working on a project where I have a static image as background and I need to put some Views on specific locations relatively to some elements that appears on the background picture.
When I'm using FrameLayout or RelativeLayout and trying to measure the exact dp from the corners I get different results for different screens sizes and the relation with the background image is lost.
I try thinking for solutions. Maybe I need to measure the image background size on the fly and then try to calculate the exact position? Or maybe put some "water marks" in the background images and get the correct positions by scanning the bitmap on the fly.
What is the best approach?